# wifi not enabling "device not ready"

Tags: networking, wireless

I have a new install of ubuntu 16 on an HP 17-X108CA laptop.

The wifi is not working; when I go into "system settings" and "network" and attempt to turn the wireless on, the switch immediately returns to the "off" position.

When I click on the network icon at the top, I can place a checkmark in "Enable Wi-Fi," and the checkmark will appear, but nothing significant happens as a result. "Wi-Fi Networks" is greyed out and indicates "device not ready."

I did some googling and although I didn't find a solution, I was able to gather a bit more information. When I enter "rfkill list" I get:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I enter "lshw -C network" I get the following:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: 30:e1:71:2d:f7:cf
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=135.23.75.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:126 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 10
       serial: 10:f0:05:59:99:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-54-generic firmware=22.361476.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 memory:b1100000-b1101fff
```

I'm fairly new to linux and am not sure what to try next. I'm using a wired connection for now and so I can download updates if need be.

One thing I noticed is during the install of ubuntu, there was an option to install 3rd party drivers (including wifi) after reboot. This required me to set up a password for disabling some sort of protected boot mode, but after the reboot this never happened.

edit: I should also note that there's no wifi switch on the laptop itself. Furthermore, wifi works fine when I boot into windows. Here is the result of the wireless info script:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24849311/

edit2: here are the laptop specs, if it helps: https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c05333508

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Have you tried to unblock the device ? So 'sudo rfkill unblock acer-wireless'. In fact, you could just unblock everything with 'sudo rfkill unblock all'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pastebin under loaded modules, we see:

```
sparse_keymap          16384  4 intel_hid,acer_wmi,intel_vbtn,hp_wmi
wmi                    16384  2 acer_wmi,hp_wmi
video                  40960  2 acer_wmi,i915
```

Your laptop is not *both* an Acer and an HP. Let's unload the *acer_wmi* module and see if it helps. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist acer-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r acer-wmi
exit
```

Any improvement? It may take a reboot.

Comment: Yes, this worked - thank you! Thanks also to hatterman.